# Vuejs v-show and v-if , data are displayed and hide immediately after

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to hide a section if an object is null. The problem is that when I refresh the page, I see that section and is hidden immediately after. I try to use v-show, but the result is the same.

```
<b-card  v-if="terminateContractValues">

export default {
    props:['terminateContractValues']
}
```

The section is hidden after I receive data from server (get request)

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: add more details please

Comment: Is `terminateContractValues`  `true` by default?

Comment: Set default value for terminateContractValues.

Comment: In the parent I set a default value terminateContractValues: {} .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.
Default it was set as object {}.

I replace `terminateContractValues: {}`  with `terminateContractValues: ''`

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value for the prop

```
<b-card  v-if="terminateContractValues">

export default {
    props: {
      terminateContractValues: {
        default: false
      }
    },
  }
```